How can I make an executable Bash file?
I have four Python scripts and one Excel table. I have to run the last Python script which opens a dashboard in my browser with Dash. I did this for my company and I want now that other people with no programming background can just click on the file and the dashboard opens directly. I read that I can do this with a Bash file, but the first problem is that I have to give the source of where the Python scripts are located, and this is different from user to user, and also it opens not directly when I click on it. Also is it possible to make one for a Mac system and one for a Windows system or maybe all in one?
This is what I tried:
My Bash script at the moment:
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname"$0")"
source/Users/myname/Documents/company/env/bin/activate
python3 Dashboard.py &
open http://126.0.0.2:8050


Well, Bash doesn't exist on Windows by default (outside of WSL), so that's out of the question. You might have a better time packaging your Python program with e.g. PyInstaller.

Clicking on some icon to cause something to happen is a function of the Window managaer. You need to specify, which operating system you are using (and, in case of Linux, which Window manager). If you need an answer for more than one platform, ask separate questions for each platform.

The immediate solution for your needs is to write a Bash script that dynamically locates the directory of your script, stores this location in a variable, and uses it to execute your script. This approach should work well for macOS and Linux users, as both systems typically support Bash. For Windows users, if they have the latest OS version with Bash support set up (through WSL, for instance), the same script might work; otherwise, a separate batch script will be necessary.
However, managing multiple scripts across different operating systems can quickly become a high-maintenance task, especially as your user base grows. A more robust and scalable solution would be to package your application into a standalone executable:
Packaging your Application into an Executable
Use PyInstaller to bundle your Python scripts into standalone executables. This tool simplifies deployment by packaging everything your application needs to run into a single file.
Future Scope
If needed, you can later integrate this application with a framework like Electron to develop a standalone desktop application. This approach offers a native user experience and could further simplify deployment and usage.
Distribution to Users
Distribute the built executables to your users. This method not only streamlines the installation process but also minimizes potential setup errors related to different user environments.
By adopting this packaging strategy, you can significantly reduce the complexity of deployment and provide a more professional, user-friendly solution to your end users.
